# Automating Repeated Unions

Tags: sql, hive, presto

I'm running a query like this:

```
SELECT id FROM table
WHERE table.type IN (1, 2, 3)
LIMIT 15
```

This returns a random sampling. I might have 7 items from `class_1` and 3 items from `class_2`. I would like to return exactly 5 items from each class, and the following code works:

```
SELECT id FROM (
SELECT id, type FROM table WHERE type = 1 LIMIT 5
UNION
SELECT id, type FROM table WHERE type = 2 LIMIT 5
UNION ...
ORDER BY type ASC)
```

This gets unwieldy if I want a random sampling from ten classes, instead of only three. What is the best way to do this?

(I'm using Presto/Hive, so any tips for those engines would be appreciated).

Comment: Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` makes little sense.

Comment: @TheImpaler You're right, this is just doing a random sampling. Tried to make it as simple an example as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a function like `row_number` to do this. This makes the selection independent of the number of types.

```
SELECT id,type
FROM (SELECT id, type, row_number() over(partition by type order by id) as rnum --adjust the partition by and order by columns as needed
      FROM table
     ) T 
WHERE rnum <= 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest adding `ORDER BY`. Anyway, you can do something like:

```
with
x as (
  select
    id,
    type,
    row_number() over(partition by type order by id) as rn
  from table
)
select * from x where rn <= 5
```